# Comparar fechas antes de ingresarlas a BD Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

soy novato en el desarrollo de Bases de datos sql de oracle,

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de comparar la fecha actual del sistema con la ingresada para validar que sea mayor desde el Command line de la base de datos Oracle.

por ejemplo:

//creo una tabla con un valor de tipo DATE

CREATE TABLE ejemplo(fecha DATE);

//Inserta fecha en la tabla , LO QUE QUIERO ES QUE VALIDE EL VALOR INSERTADO PARA VER SI ES UNA FECHA MAYOR A LA FECHA ACTUAL

INSERT INTO ejemplo VALUE('10-JAN-2019');

Comment: Bienvenido/a a StackOverflow, en realidad hay muchas formas de hacerlo. Tu pregunta, sin embargo, no es lo suficientemente precisa. Por favor haz el [tour]  y lee [ask]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

supongo que estas en una función o un procedimiento, en ese caso antes de insertar la fecha deberías comparar el parámetro de entrada tal vez algo así:

```
if to_date(p_fecha, 'yyyy/mm/dd') = trunc(sysdate) then ...
```

- p_fecha es el parámetro.
- 'yyyy/mm/dd' como formato o el que ocupes.-

de todas maneras podrías indicar mas detalles como por ejemplo en que capa quieres hacer la evaluación, etc.

Saludos.